# can i add component selectors in index.html in angular2

Tags: angular

I made a header component in order to keep my header consistent throughout the website so that I dont have to write the header code repeatedly. On placing the selector in the index.html file, I couldn't see the result. Please tell the correct way to do that

index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>stuff</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-root></app-root>


</body>

</html>
```

i just have a paragraph tag saying 'header works' in my headerComponent and it is all generated by angular-cli, no modifications made.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the app.component.html above `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` tag as:-

`<div>
     <app-header></app-header>
</div>
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>`

Comment: can't it be used in index.html directly?

Comment: I guess No because at the time index.html is rendered it has no information about <app-header> as <app-root> is the starting point of the application.

Comment: this will solve the purpose i.e. header consistent throughout the website.